# Permission denied to access property 'href'

Tags: javascript, permission-denied

I try to reload parent web page from iframe. Here is my code:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.parent.location.href = window.parent.location.href;      
});
 </script>
```

But it doesn´t work. Firebug says: Permission denied to access property 'href'

I´m on same domain so what´s the problem? I try to do it in Wordpress theme.

Comment: I think you mean that without `()` since it's not a function.

Comment: *I´m on same domain* — What are the *absolute* URIs of the two pages?

Comment: Can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 9):

Your code will be working only when the parent and child are running from the same protocol(http/https), same host and same port. This is known as Same Origin Policy (SOP).
You can check the below reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

You can set `document.domain="domainName:port"` in Firefox. It can't set a default value of port, you should set by yourself, if the port is different！