# IE7 JavaScript location.href permission error

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am receiving a JavaScript error in IE7: `you don't have permission`.

In IE8+, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari there is no problem with this code.

Why does this error only occur in IE7? And how would I change my code using JaScript and Ajax?

**Code:**

```
login: function () {
    var a = location.href;
    if (loginCurrentFullUrl != null && loginCurrentFullUrl != "") {
        a = loginCurrentFullUrl;
    }
    var b = location.href.substring(location.href.length - 1);
    if (b.indexOf("/") > -1) {
        a = location.href.substring(0, location.href.length - 1);
    }
    location.href = "/pc/login/?url=" + encodeURIComponent(a);
},
```

or

```
var o = location.toString();
```

**Error code:**
('you don't have permission')

```
var a = location.href;
var o = location.toString();
```

I tried:

```
document.location.href;
window.location.href;
```

I also tried:

```
document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
```

Neither has worked.

Comment: Do you have to specify `window.location.href` instead of `location.href`? Do you have an `iframe` on the page?

Comment: Is this the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798990/permission-denied-to-access-property-href

Comment: i tried already.
document.location / window.location but didn't worked

Comment: i don't include iframe. only javascript class & ajax